# Begin vs Start in examples

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

I was wondering what the difference is between these pairs of examples:

- Okay, so if we are going to work where do we **begin**?
- Okay, so if we are going to work where do we **start**?

And

- We are going to have a party tomorrow. We should **start** making preparations today.
- We are going to have a party tomorrow. We should **begin** making preparations today.

Comment: There are certain contexts where one may sound more natural or idiomatic or formal than the other; however, in your examples here, they both pretty much mean the same thing and neither one sounds awkward.

Comment: With the *work* pair, *begin* makes *where* sound more metaphysical (references some kind of 'state') - e.g. begin *by sorting the register*; *start* makes *where* sound more literal (references a location) - e.g. start *at the door*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference in these examples.

*Start* can be used with machines and engines to express the process of transitioning them from a non-running state to a running state.  So you will hear *start your engines* but never *begin your engines*.

*Start* can also be phrasally used with *up*, *out with*, and also *over* but these don't work with *begin* (*start over* = *begin again*, *start again* works too).

*Start* and *stop* are often paired, and *begin* and *end* are often paired.

Other than that *start* and *begin* are interchangeable.